# Select specific value in dynamic SQL

Tags: python, sqlite

Im creating a text game, and its starts with user adds some details and save it into sql database and this is reused later in game rooms.

My question I cannot not fetch only name when specifc game start in a room, all details is listed, but I only needs to see the name (first_nam)

FYI: Database creation and view() function is done in one file and calculation part is done another file connected

```
from UserAccoutDetailsBackEndOOP import Database_input
database_input=Database_input("accountdetails.db")
view = Database_input
```

The result of when program is runinng:
please select what calculation you want perform '+',  '-', '/', '*' or 'change calculation method' +
1
John
None
Doe
89
2022-08-02 20:32:55.528170

```
self.conn = sqlite3.connect("accountdetails.db")
self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name text, enter_middle_name text, sur_name text, age integer, Timestamp integer)")
self.conn.commit()

def view(self):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    rows = self.cur.fetchone()
    return rows


calculation_input = input("please select what calculation you want perform '+',  '-', '/', '*' or 'change calculation method' ")
    self.view() # only display name
```

Comment: Why do you select `*` if you want the name. Why not `first_name, *`?

Comment: Right, OR just `print(rows[0])` to print the first field?

Comment: Im not sure how its working with sql :-) but this list can contain muliple user, every time game starts its asking for same details (first_name etc.) so it can contain mutiple user and Im fetching the latest added user

Comment: So you want the top user of `first_name`? Use `limit` together with your `select` or simply the first value?

Comment: yes, I want the user first_name, but when reastarting the game, the first_name I want see has changed to id 2 (new player added)

Comment: @NelsonGon I tested this, If I understood you correct         self.cur.execute("first_name , * FROM book ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") 
but I got error please select what calculation you want perform '+',  '-', '/', '*' or 'change calculation method' +
Invalid input: near "first_name": syntax error please enter a new number

Comment: You still need to include `select` in your `execute`.

Comment: Ok :-) I did this
        self.cur.execute("SELECT first_name, * FROM book ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
and John was displayed first, but I can still see the rest of details
John
1
John
None
Doe
89
2022-08-02 20:32:55.528170
None

Comment: You can modify to only show what you need. This was simply like rearranging. You select first name and everything that follows. Remove `*` and either keep only first name or any other columns you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your help its was working., not sure how I can added score to you regarding this, but big thanks for your help :-)